# vim ctags open split screen after choosing from list of definitions

Tags: vim, ctags

I want to imitate "pycharm" effect of choosing multiple definitions in vim. Im using ctags and have two options in my `.vimrc`, but don't know how to bind them

1) mapping default ctrl+] combination to show list of definitions

```
map <C-]> g<C-]>
```

2) after choosing definition from list, i press enter, and at this moment i want to open split screen below the current buffer

```
map <C-]> :rightbelow vsplit <CR> :exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

but function definition opens in new tab...

Comment: Thanks for fixing the title; please also do proper formatting of the commands. It's hard to read this way, and you're struggling with the < and > being interpreted as tags. Just indent the lines by 4 spaces!

Comment: sorry about this, i'm new here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g<c-]>` is equivalent to `:tjump`. `:stjump` is a split variant of `:tjump`.

```
nnoremap <c-]> :<c-u>rightbelow vertical stjump <c-r><c-w><cr>
```

General rule of thumbs:

- Supply a mode for your mapping. `n` for normal in this case.
- Use `noremap` over `map` unless you are using a `<Plug>` mapping.

For more help see:

```
:h :vert
:h :stjump
:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W
```